# Pbiviz start error "LESS style/visual.less"

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-code, powerbi, autodesk-forge, pbiviz

I am following the tutorial found on https://github.com/xiaodongliang/forgeviewer_embed_in_powerbi_report to create a custom visual in PowerBi.
In order to visualize the 3d model The author recommends installing the visual tools at 2.5.0 version, otherwise it won't work

> npm i -g powerbi-visuals-tools@2.5.0

(I actually tried the same procedure installing the 3.2.0 instead of 2.5.0 and in fact it didn't work, the custom visual remained blank instead of showing me the model, so i'm restarting the procedure with the 2.5.0 api version)

Running the command "pbiviz start" it gives me this error:

```
PS C:\Users\Gian Marco Manfredi\circlecard> pbiviz start
 info   Building visual...
 error  LESS  style/visual.less :  The "data" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, TypedArray, or DataView. Received undefined
```

the visual.less is

```
p {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    em {
        background: yellow;
        padding: 5px;
        
    }
}
```

and the pbiviz.json is

```
{
  "visual": {
    "name": "circleCard",
    "displayName": "CircleCard",
    "guid": "circleCardA2677EDA579643169880D5D3DF0E2A32",
    "visualClassName": "Visual",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "",
    "supportUrl": "",
    "gitHubUrl": ""
  },
  "apiVersion": "2.5.0",
  "author": {
    "name": "",
    "email": ""
  },
  "assets": {
    "icon": "assets/icon.png"
  },
  "externalJS": [
    "node_modules/powerbi-visuals-utils-dataviewutils/lib/index.js"
  ],
  "style": "style/visual.less",
  "capabilities": "capabilities.json",
  "dependencies": "dependencies.json",
  "stringResources": []
}
```

I hope somebody could help me

Thank you!

Comment: I guess it is because of the issue of the pbiviz tool version.. did you run the code which is downloaded from my sample github repository, or you built the code project from scratch?  In my sample repository, there is a folder .api/v2.5.0 which stores some required files when working with 2.5

Comment: Hi! you're right, the 2.5 was the right version to make it work.  I changed Typescript to 2.3.3 version and deleted a d3 library which i installed in the wrong position and now everytingh works! thank you for you help! I also asked another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69209886/autodesk-forge-highlight-child-object to modify your code and I would really appreciate your help. thank you again!

Comment: great to know it works now. :)  and it looks some community gurus have shared comments for your other question. Hope it helps.