# Autodesk forge highlight child object

Tags: visual-studio-code, powerbi, autodesk-forge, forge

Recently i've been working on this repository https://github.com/xiaodongliang/forgeviewer_embed_in_powerbi_report to build a custom visual in Power BI to visualize the issues extracted from Bim track'S API.

The idea was visualizing them in associaton to the model's ROOMS.
In order to do that I worked with a NWC file, so i cuold export rooms as a geometry.

What i would like to do now is to highligt the rooms if a connected issue is selected from a table.
The problem is When i select an issue from a table, in the selection tree i can see highlighted the parent object name (ROOM) instead of the child (solid), and i think that is why i can't achieve my purpose (if not please correct me).

[what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Msxtc.png)

[what i wold like to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNDnw.png)

Does anyone know a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to change your selection between `(FIRST_OBJECT, LAST_OBJECT, LEAF_OBJECT)` you can change viewer selection settings in order to test:

[image]

If you would like to achieve this programmatically :

```
Viewer.setSelectionMode();
```

could help you as well.

Answer (score 0):

If I well understood, you want to highlight the child (which contain the mesh) instead of the parent.

The object highlight (isolate) is done in `/forgePowerbiView/src/visual.ts` with this code:

```
const dbIds = options.dataViews[0].table.rows.map(r => 
                <number>r[0].valueOf());
console.log('dbIds: '  +dbIds)
        
this.forge_viewer.showAll();
this.forge_viewer.impl.setGhostingBrightness(true); //for isolate effect 
this.forge_viewer.isolate(dbIds);
```

Take a look at this link [Enumerating leaf nodes on Viewer](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/enumerating-leaf-nodes-viewer). This will help you to get the `dbIds` you want to isolate.